# Matlab video capture with audio (s-video)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-capture

I want to record a video using a USB frame grabber and Matlab's image acquisition toolbox. I managed to record it but unfortunately there was no sound in the video. My frame grabber has an s-video port and I was using it. I know that S-video can capture video, but I don't understand why it's not saving audio in Matlab. I used some desktop video capture softwares and they got the audio with the video. Here is my code at the moment

```
vid=videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'YUY2_360x240');
src = getselectedsource(vid);
vid.SelectedSourceName = 'svideo';
vid.FramesPerTrigger = 1;

vid.FramesPerTrigger = Inf;

vid.LoggingMode = 'disk';


% auto save of the file by the date of the day
j=1;
while exist(fullfile(folder_name,[strrep(date,'-','_') '_' num2str(ID)  '_' 
num2str(j) '.avi']), 'file') == 2
j=j+1;
end
diskLogger =VideoWriter(fullfile(folder_name,[strrep(date,'-','_') '_' 
num2str(ID)  '_' num2str(j) '.avi']),'Motion JPEG AVI');

vid.DiskLogger = diskLogger;

setappdata(handles.connect1,'vid',vid);


%% reset used variables and reopen comport
start(vid);
getappdata(handles.connect1,'vid',vid);

stop(vid);
```

How can I get the audio in my video?
Thanks

Comment: There is no code related to any audio-source (i'm assuming videoinput is only treating video as you only give info about some raw video-stream) and also no code related to put some audio into the video-container (MJPEG is a video-codec; of course it know no audio). Maybe read [this](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/30727-simultaneous-video-and-audio-acquisition).

Comment: I'm assuming since my video contains sound and since my audio wires are connected to the usb video grabber, it should also be receiving the sound information. That's why I didn't add an audio recording part (I thought it was embedded with the video).

Comment: That's unlikely as it seems your grabber is outputting raw streams (```YUY2_360x240```). For something to contain video and audio, one needs some container (avi, mkv, mp4, ...), but that's just not the output the grabber seems to pipe out. Maybe better to use the working tools with lossless output (which can then be later processed) if you can afford the space needed.

Comment: Oh yes, I get it now. Since I know that this usb grabber can capture audio (using its own software not Matlab), I thought of aquiring the sound using the data acquisition tool. I still couldn't recognize the usb grabber as a DAQ device (I think more drivers are needed if it can be used as an audio DAQ device). So the image acquisition toolbox will get the video and the data acquisition toolbox will get the audio at the same time, (I don't mind having Audio and video separate), Will this idea be logical?

Comment: Isn't that covered in my link with all the potential problems? We don't know anything about your grabber and what's it outputting how. I usually consider these more or less black-boxes with some crazy driver-stuff needed to use (which is hard to achieve in matlab). Even if you somehow get both streams, you probably have no kind of synchronization (which is a hard problem in it's core and probably abstracted away within the drivers).

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't notice the link, but yest that's what I thought of.  It seems that synchronization will be an issue and it's important in my case. I'm not sure if there is an alternative to using the image acquisition toolbox, unless I could somehow managed to control the grabber's software from Matlab so that it can start recording as soon as my program starts and stops when my program stops.